# Rate content by the author's role

Tags: nodes, rating

I want a five-star content rating system, for example: 
if a premium user creates a content this will be rated with five starts, if a simple user creates a content this will be rated with three starts etc. I dont wont users to rate the conten.
Is something like this possible ???

Comment: Erm, maybe not my place to say, but misleading your users into thinking one piece of content is better than another simply because it's been _paid_ for is not a good thing to do.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but this is the project's scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume your using Drupal 7, you want to look into [hook_node_update()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) this will allow you to run code whenever a node is saved/created.

From there you'll have full access to the node object in which you can use [user_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load/7) to grab the user object and check it's roles. Then you need to add logic based on the role to modify the nodes fivestar rating.

Comment: I should create a custom module ??

Comment: Yes your hooks and logic will have to go in a custom module. A good place to start is - https://drupal.org/developing/modules